# How to encrypt and decrypt Map<String, Map<String,String>> in Java?

Tags: java, encryption, data-structures

I want to store the password details in to sever,for that i need to  encrypt and decrypt the following `Map<String, Map<String,Strin`g>>`map =....` 
Example:

```
Map<String,Map<String,String> map = ...
String encoded = new String(Base64.encodeBase64( jso.toString( 4 ).toByteArray()));
```

I read this map to JSON and then i encode the value. In this approached i store the details in to local variable then I encrypt and decrypt.

Is there any better way to encrypt and decrypt following Map `Map<String,Map<String,String>`

Thanks

Comment: For passwords you should never, ever have a way to decrypt them.
Hash the original password, and when you wish to compare it, hash the user password before transmitting it and compare the hashes.

Comment: Base64 encoding is *not* "encryption".